# conversion from 'node*' to non-scalar type 'node' requested in C++

Tags: c++, struct, nodes

I just tried to create a sudoku solver using C++ (with basic C) by using linked list machanism. While doing that i got the error like

- In function `node addnode(int, node*)`:
- `Line 29: error: conversion from 'node*' to non-scalar type 'node' requested`
- compilation terminated due to `-Wfatal-errors`.

In function `node addnode(int, node*)`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int cellvalue;
    int cellpos;
    int rowpos;
    int colpos;
    int blockpos;
    node *next;
} cells[81];

struct node addnode (int value,struct node *lastpos)
{
    node *newnode;
    newnode=new node;
    newnode->cellvalue = value;
    newnode->cellpos=value;
    newnode->rowpos=value%9;
    newnode->colpos=value/9;
    newnode->blockpos=0;
    lastpos->next=newnode;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    printf("Value : %d", newnode->cellvalue);
    lastpos=newnode;
    return &lastpos;
}

int main()
{
    int i=0,value;
    node *header, *lastnodeaddr, *lastpos;
    lastnodeaddr=NULL;
    for (i=0;i<81;i++)
        lastnodeaddr=addnode (i,lastnodeaddr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
lastnodeaddr=addnode (i,lastnodeaddr);
```

`lastnodeaddr` is a pointer to `node`, but `addnode` returns a `node` by value.

Answer (score -1):

In `addnode` `lastpos` is a pointer to `node` and you are returning `&lastpos` which means a double pointer as `node**` but `addnode` is declared to return `node` by value hence the error.